# Cache with cache invalidation and lazy source subscription

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

What I want:

- I have some `Observable<T>`
- I want to cache it's emitted value
- I want to cache it's emitted value only until I reset the cache
- after cache invalidation any subscriber should get the new data automatically

**Idee**

I create a `BehaviourRelay` that subscribes to the source `Observable` and caches it's last value. Whenever the cache should be invalidated, I unsubscribe the relay from the source and resubscribe it to it again.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class RxCache<T>(
        private val observable: Observable<T>,
        private val tag: String = "RxCache"
) {

    private val source: Observable<T>
    private var disposable: Disposable? = null
    private val relay = BehaviorRelay.create<T>()

    init {
        // ) 1) create a new hot observable - 
        // as we will subscribe to it after every reload again
        source = observable.share()
                .doAfterNext {
                    L.d(tag, "data loaded")
                }
        // 2) first reload call
        reload()
    }

    fun reload() {
        // 1) unsubscribe from old observable
        disposable?.dispose()
        disposable = null
        // 2) subscribe relay again to reload data
        disposable = source.subscribe(relay)
    }

    fun observe(): Observable<T> {
        return relay.hide()
                .doAfterNext {
                    L.d(tag, "data emitted")
                }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I want that the `relay` only subscribes to the `source` if it either has a subscriber itself or as soon as the first subscriber subscribes to the relay. The first thing is easy, but I don't know how to solve the second thing in a safe way.

Any ideas? Or alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As you have figured out, it is impossible to "remove" last value from `BehaviorSubject`. I think your code karate with internal Observable passed via is not good solution in multiple ways. This is the code what may help you:

```
sealed class CacheItem<T> { // (1)
    class Data<T>(val data: T) : CacheItem<T>()
    class Reset<T> : CacheItem<T>()
}

class RxCache<T> {

    private val behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<CacheItem<T>> = BehaviorSubject.create()

    fun reset() {
        behaviorSubject.onNext(CacheItem.Reset()) // (2)
    }

    fun add(newItem: T) {
        behaviorSubject.onNext(CacheItem.Data(newItem)) // (3)
    }

    fun observe() : Observable<T> {
        return behaviorSubject.hide()
            .filter { it != CacheItem.Reset<T>() } // (4)
            .map { (it as CacheItem.Data<T>).data } // (5)
    }
}
```

Let's explain interesting marked parts:

1. I have created CacheItem which indicates if `subject` currently holds cached data or if reload/reset has been performed.
2. Everytime you want to "reset" subject, you push `Reset` object to it, to indicate there are no data available.
3. In case you want to add new cached data you simply push data wrapped in `CacheItem.Data` class into the subject.
4. We want to ignore all reset values and receive only emitted `Data` items.
5. Finally we remove `CacheItem.Data` wrapper and get raw cached value.

Comment: Actually, I did this way of invalidation in a subject in the past already (just came to my mind when I saw your suggestion). I think this solves the issues, will try it out

Comment: The problem is, that I don't want to clear the cache but I want to start a reload instead. Any ideas on this? The reload must be initialed from within the `RxCache` class (like in my example), I don't want anyone from outside to push new data into the cache (like your example would force someone to call `add(newItem)`)

Comment: @prom85 Reload is executed trough source observable you pass in constructor? Am i right?

Comment: The source observable is a cold observable that emits a single value in my case. I share it inside the rxcache and make it hot - so each subscriber executes the cold base observable again. So in my solution reloading is executed through subscription to the base observable - the observable passed in my classes constructor.

Comment: @prom85 Why do you want to cache values if you execute cold observable everytime someone subscribes? You can already call source observable and get new values, don't you?

Comment: I don't want subscribers to know anything about the cache. This is some internal business logic. E.g. I want to observe the list of files in a directory - if I delete/edit/... a file in it, I want to reload/update the cache and all observers of the directory should get the new data automatically - the source observable in this case simply gets all files from directory. The cache is used as a hot observable

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the low-tech version:

```
Map<T, Observable<T> caches = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

/* .... */
caches.computeIfAbsent(key, k ->  generateSourceObservable(k).cache())
      .doOnNext(...) // or whatever,  continue your processing pipeline.
```

Then you can just clear or remove keys from the cache, and the existing reactive streams will not be affected.

Comment: that's exactly the opposite of what I want - I want to effect all existing streams, I just want to clear a cache in the middle of a stream. That's why I'm currently pushing new data through a relay which always stays the same. currently the relay subscribes to new observables, but every observer of a cache always subscribers (and keeps subscribed) to the same relay